# DiscordJs Event Handler With SubFolders And Aliases

Tags: discord.js

I have the following code which i have from a tutorial. I would like to extend it so  there are subfolders (instead of just one command folder) and aliases if the user knows a different and shorter name for the command.

I added aliases and modules line, but am not sure how to implement those in in code that i have.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = require('./config.json');
const modules = ["administration", "fun", "misc", "information"];

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Philomena is ready for action!');
  client.user.setActivity("`ph.help`")
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});


client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just repeat what you already have for every sub-folder:

```js
const subCommandACmds = fs.readdirSync('./commands/subCommandA').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of subCommandACmds) {
    const command = require(`./commands/subCommandA/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const subCommandBCmds = fs.readdirSync('./commands/subCommandB').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of subCommandBCmds) {
    const command = require(`./commands/subCommandB/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Comment: would I change the first part of the code or place it under the code?

Comment: You wouldn't need to change anything, all you're doing is duplicating that block of code and renaming a variable along with editing the sub-folder name

Comment: ah. and would i delete the declaration of modules line?

Comment: You wouldn't need that.

Answer (score 0):

To have your bot also retrieve the commands from subfolders, you could use a function like this:

```js
client.commands=new Discord.Collection();
loadCommands(client.commands, './commands');

function loadCommands(collection, directory){
    const files = fs.readdirSync(directory);

    for (const file of files) { 
        const path=`${directory}/${file}`;
        
        if(file.endsWith('.js')){
            const command = require(path);
            collection.set(command.name, command); 
        }
        else if(fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()){
            loadCommands(collection, path);
        }
    }
};
```